# Azure Bot Service Slack Integration

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm currently evaluating Azure Bot Service using Azure Function as a Slack bot.

It works fine with direct and group messages, but I'm having troubles to make it work with app_mention events, the azure function is not getting fired at all.

Also, i'd like to experiment with slash commands, which are also a feature available to slack app.

Reading the docs, I understand have to write my own middleware to parse these messages, but it's not clear to me how can I do it with Functions.

Is it possible? Or will I need to host a separate webapp?

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you want to make the bot in functions specifically, rather than in a web app? It isn't clear as no code or overall description of the bot itself and where you are having design difficulties is present in the question.

Comment: Sorry for being so late at answering. 
Making the bot in functions was a constraint to keep as low as possible the effort and budget needed to have a functioning prototype.
This had to be an internal evaluation tool, and we had no experience with full-fledged bot framework.

Comment: out of interest which framework are you using V3 or V4?

Comment: azure functions supports only framework v3 as of today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that Azure Bot Service is currently supporting a subset of Slack events out-of-the-box; this was not clearly stated in the documentation.

We ended up with a first prototype based on Bot Service integrated with the basic Slack events, will evaluate it and then proceed with a full bot-framework WebApp if needed.